# Swift: Can I adjust attributed text with dynamic font size?

Tags: swift, dynamic, size, collectionview

I'm working with the collectionView
whose each cell has the content like this: [image]

everything works pretty well until I test it on an iphone 5s:[image]

"Ho Chi Minh City" was out of bounds.
Here is my code:

```
func configureNameLabel() {
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: post?.name ?? "", attributes: [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)])
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\nSaturday, December 1, 2018 ⦁ Ho Chi Minh City ⦁ ", attributes:
        [.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, .font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)]))

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.string.count))

    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = UIImage(named: "user-male")
    attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -2, width: 12, height: 12)
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))

    nameLabel.attributedText = attributedText
}
```

I think this problem is due to the font size, can anybody fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried `numberOfLines = 0`?

Comment: @excitedmicrobe it didn't work also. I think it is because of the attributed text, not the normal text.

Comment: I think the issue is that the height of your label is not increasing. Have you tried checking your constraints on the label? they should be such that width is calculated and fixed and does not grow with content.

Comment: Is the `configureNameLabel` height Static or Dynamic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I solved it. "label.numberOfLines = 0" worked. the problem is at my constraints.